# Gridview textbox on Page_load enable edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studio.2008.R2;
```

N00b here,

I've got the gridview to look the way I want it to (a textbox inside of the `ItemTemplate`). The Textbox's class has some client-sideJS that enables a save button (an `asp:LinkButton` set to look like a Jquery UI save icon)  to become visible after the Textbox's `.keypress` event fires..
Now for my question..
I've looked everywhere, but I can't get how to have gridview put the Sql server db content in that textbox on Page_load (one textbox + `<br />` for each row). I'm only printing one collumn from the Sql server db into the Gridview.. Also, how would I bind the `asp:LinkButton` save button to gridview's save event? If there is a more effecient way to do this? If you have some insight for me, please give me your opinion/!

*My .aspx code*

```
         <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="hexen" runat="server" DataField="TbValue" SortExpression="TbValue">

                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FluxConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [TbValue] FROM [InvestigateValues]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your text box to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="hexen" runat="server" text='<%#Bind("TbValue")%>' />
```

This will enable two way databinding.

Here is an article to get you started: http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/35058.

The grid view and SqlDataSource expose Insert, Update and Delete event/methods. These are on a **row** level, not grid level.

The way I would approach your problem would be to have an onclick event for your link button that iterates through the gridview, get the data from each text box and then perform the appropriate data base action in the code behind.

Comment: This worked for me, but the "text" attribute has a typo.. Should be `text='<%#Bind("TbValue")%>'` instead of `text='<%#Bind("TbValue")%'>`